# Find $f([-1,2])$ if $f:R\to R$ and $f(x)=x^2$.

Tags: calculus, functions

May someone confirm if im right on this exercise:

I gotta find $f([-1,2])$ if $f:R\to R$ and $f(x)=x^2$

So is the answer $[1,4]$?

Comment: incorrect......

Comment: I guess here you're supposed to find the minimum and maximum of the function in the given interval. So you don't just stick the end values to the function and hope for the best.

Comment: Observe that $f(0)=0$

Comment: hmm, then i need more help

Comment: Are you familiar with monotonic functions ?

Answer (score 3):

See [this graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E2%20from%20x%3D-1%20to%202) so you can get were you problem is.

Finding $f([-1,2])$ means finding all the values $f(x)$ takes when $x$ takes values in $[-1,2]$

What you did was calculating $f(-1)$ and $f(2)$. It would have been correct if $f$ was monotonic on $[-1,2]$ (always increasing, or always decreasing).

However, as you can see from the graph (and maybe already knew), $x \rightarrow x²$ is decreasing on$]-\infty,0]$ and increasing on $[0, +\infty[$.

So as for user108128 answer, you have to work on $[-1,0]$ and $[0,2]$. $f$ being monotonic on these intervals, you can then use your method.

Answer (score 1):

More help is with $-1\leq x\leq2$ then you have two intervals $[-1,0]\cup[0,2]$, now for these intervals $f([-1,0])=[0,1]$ and $f([0,2])=[0,4]$. Then $f([-1,2])=[0,1]\cup[0,4]=[0,4]$.